# Javafx FXML loader getcontroller returns null

Tags: javafx, fxml

In my program i have a tabPane  with each tab having in own FXML file and controller .I have loaded the FXML file for tab 2 (Schedular).I`m trying to call a function in my child controller (Scheduler) from my parent controller(FXML Document) . When i load the controller using FXML Loader it returns a null. How can i solve this .

Here is my main code:

Main FXMLDocument :

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="600" prefWidth="800" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65"   fx:controller="showprojavafxml.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FXMLLoader` only instantiates the controller when it loads the fxml file (this has to be the case, since the controller class is specified in the fxml file...). Since you never call `load()` on the loader, the controller is never created.

It looks like you are referencing the FXML file twice through two different mechanisms: once in `FXMLDocumentController.initialize()`, where you create a `FXMLLoader` whose location is set to the fxml file, and once in the main FXML document itself, via a `<fx:include>`. The `<fx:include>` is causing the UI defined in `Scheduler.fxml` to be displayed; the `FXMLLoader` you create in the `initialize()` method is not (because you never call `load()` and display the result).

To reference a controller for an included fxml, use the ["Nested controller" technique](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers).

First, add an `fx:id` to your `fx:include`:

```xml
<Tab fx:id="tab2" text="Scheduler"   >
    <fx:include fx:id="scheduler" source="Scheduler.fxml" />
</Tab>
```

Now you can inject the controller into a field whose name is the `fx:id` with the text `"Controller"` appended:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController {

    @FXML
    private SchedulerController schedulerController ;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        schedulerController.refreshList();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I have gotten it to be able to call the the function from my second controller but its not updating on my current screen but the function is run.

Comment: But now you are calling `load()`, but you are not displaying the UI you get when you load the FXML. The the controller is managing a UI that is not visible.

Comment: Ah, you also have an `<fx:include>` which is actually displaying the fxml. See updated answer.

Comment: Works beautifully .Thanks Mate